# Missing multipart field ‘operations’ with graphql-upload and apollo-server

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

Hello I am trying to upload a file using graphql in order to do this I have the following code:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { graphqlUploadExpress } = require('graphql-upload');


async function startApolloServer() {
  

  const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      hello: () => 'Hello world!',
    },
    Mutation: {
      singleUpload: async (parent, { file }) => {
        const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;
        const stream = createReadStream();
        const out = require('fs').createWriteStream(filename);
        stream.pipe(out);
        return { filename, mimetype, encoding, url: '' }
      }
    }
  };

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs:gql`
    type Query {
      hello: String!
    }
    type UploadedFileResponse {
      filename: String!
      mimetype: String!
      encoding: String!
      url: String!
    }
    type Mutation {
      singleUpload(file: Upload!): UploadedFileResponse!
    }`
  , resolvers },{uploads:false});
  await server.start();

  const app = express();
  app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 1000000000, maxFiles: 10 }));

  server.applyMiddleware({ app });

  await new Promise(resolve => app.listen({ port: 4000 }, resolve));
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
  return { server, app };
}

startApolloServer()
```

And in order to call the endpoint I am using the following curl:

```
curl localhost:4000/graphql \
  -F operations='{ "query": "mutation ($file: Upload!) { singleUpload(file: $file) { filename } }", "variables": { "file": null } }' \
  -F map='{ "0": ["variables.file"] }' \
  -F 0=@/home/user/a.txt
```

But when I execute this I got the following error:

> Missing multipart field ‘operations’

If I remove `app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 1000000000, maxFiles: 10 }));`

I got another error

> function deprecated(...args) {
> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

But in this case I can write a empty file with the correct name.

Any idea about how can I finish this poc in order to upload a file using apollo-graphql.

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^2.25.2",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.25.2",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1",
    "graphql-upload": "^12.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  },
```

But I tried whit this too

```
"resolutions": {
    "**/**/fs-capacitor": "^6.2.0",
    "**/graphql-upload": "^11.0.0"
  }
```

Node version: 14.16.1 and 14.17.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. In your typDefs, add: `scalar Upload`
2. In resolvers, add: `Upload: GraphQLUpload`

GraphQLUpload is imported from 'graphql-upload': `import { GraphQLUpload } from "graphql-upload";`